# Get template parameter type of derived class in map that doesn't know about template parameters

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to get the template parameter type in this scenario:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <typeinfo>

class Base {
public:
    typedef char myType;
};

template <typename T>
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    typedef T myType;
};

int main() {
    std::map<std::string, Base*> myMap;
    myMap["test1"] = new Derived<int>();
    myMap["test2"] = new Derived<float>();

    std::cout << typeid(myMap["test1"]).name() << std::endl; // prints Base
    std::cout << typeid(myMap["test2"]).name() << std::endl; // prints Base

    //myMap["test1"]->myType test; // invalid use of 'Base::myType'

    std::cout << typeid(dynamic_cast<Derived*>(myMap["test1"])->myType).name() << std::endl; // invalid use of template-name 'Derived' without an argument list. Should print "int" ...
    std::cout << typeid(dynamic_cast<Derived*>(myMap["test2"])->myType).name() << std::endl; // invalid use of template-name 'Derived' without an argument list. Should print "float" ...
}
```

The map holds elements of type Base and thus, also of type Derived with a template parameter. However on retrieving elements from the map I am not able to get the template parameter type back again. I tried to add a typedef to both classes but it doesn't work.

Do you have hints to resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The answer really depends what you need that type for.  Types are generally resolved statically at compile time, so for most purposes you'll need to provide virtual member functions that act on appropriate base classes rather than determining the exact type of the object pointed to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do you have hints to resolve this problem?

type names don't work like `virtual` member functions. What you need is a `virtual` member function.

Here's a demonstrative program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <typeinfo>

class Base {
public:
    virtual std::type_info const& myType() const { return typeid(char); }
};

template <typename T>
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    virtual std::type_info const& myType() const { return typeid(T); }
};

int main() {
    std::map<std::string, Base*> myMap;
    myMap["test1"] = new Derived<int>();
    myMap["test2"] = new Derived<float>();

    std::cout << myMap["test1"]->myType().name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << myMap["test2"]->myType().name() << std::endl;
}
```

Output with g++:

```
i
f
```

Comment: thanks, that works perfectly! But now I try to instantiate an object of this type which is not possible by using a `std::type_info` I think. Can I somehow directly get the type T for something like `decltype(myMap["test1"]->myType()) myNewObjectOfTypeT;`?

Comment: @inspire, that's not possible from my solution. That is a different requirement. You should look up the Factory Pattern and the Builder Pattern. That might give you some ideas.